# tensorflow nested training, how to implement it

Tags: tensorflow

I meet a problem in my experiments.
 Briefly speaking, I have a series of tensor computation flow, such as `a => b => c => loss => train_op`, this is a typical scenario of tensorflow usage. However, my own problem is that, when doing `b => c`, i need to training a extra network for several steps, that's 
`a=>b=> training another network =>c=>loss=>train_op`, hence, I dnt know how to implement this?
Someone hit me that I can put the extra training network part in `tf.py_func` , but I still feel confused.

Comment: the loss and train_op are the same in the two networks?

Comment: a,b,c,loss,trian_op are in the same network. But `training another network` is another network which use the output from `b`. Hence I need nest the `another network` after `b`.

Comment: so if it is the same train_op you can calculate the gradient for each network on its own and the naverage. `optimizer.compute_gradients(a->b->c->loss); optimizer.compute_gradients(a->b->another network->c->loss)` now you have the gradients for both, you can average or sum or whatever

Comment: link the the `compute_gradient` : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#compute_gradients